# Check for Javascript events on URL in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

Ok, so I'm maintaining a legacy code where they are creating html on the backend side (a form) and in the action tag they are appending the value of the URL to make a redirect. There are no input of type texts anywhere to sanitize. The url comes from the request, they have an event handler to check if that is a redirect, etc.

Burp scan indicates that you can (of course) escape the Url and put a JavaScript event in it.

So the idea is to how can I detect if the Url has a JavaScript event, because this is already on an html we are sending I cant html encode it, because is not a text we are saving but a page they are showing.

How can I check if the string (which is the Url ) has JavaScript event escaped in it?.

What I tried is to ask if in the Url there is `'` (the escape) but I yet to know if the url can contain such symbol, so it seems I have to analyze if we are seeing a JS Event.

So the url looks something like this: `/Something/TheSession/123'onmouseover%3d'alert(1)'456`

And then they are appending that url here on a stringbuilder:

```
sb.Append("<html><body><form name='Redirect' method='post' action='")
sb.Append(request.Url.PathAndQuery)
```

I already read some references like portswigger about XSS but in the Reflected XSS Script the example is in html tags which would be easier to check.